# Como pegar o dia

Tags: php, sql

Preciso pegar somente o "dia" da data do aniversario da pessoa no SQL.

```
include("conexao.php");
$mes = date("m");
$consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM niver WHERE niver LIKE '%".$mes."%'");
   while($linha = $consulta ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {        
     echo "
"; 
     echo "Nome do Aniversariante: {$linha['nome']} 
";           
     echo "{$linha['niver']}";
   }
```

Com esse código eu consigo pegar os aniversariantes do mês atual. Mas agora eu quero mostrar somente o dia do aniversario dele.

Comment: `WHERE MONTH( niver ) = mes`

Comment: Se quer pegar o dia, literalmente, use `SELECT DAY(niver) FROM ...`, desde que esteja no formato DATETIME ou DATE....

Comment: SELECT DAY( campo ) mostra o dia, WHERE MONTH( campo ) = seleciona o mês, e se precisar de ano, tem o YEAR( campo )